# How to debug MDN Web Docs examples?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Suppose I have [Javascript example in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}

// expected output:
// "a: 1"
// "b: 2"
// "c: 3"
```

I can run it with `Run` button:

[image]

But can I trace/debug it with breakpoints with looking how it goes?

Where is the source code of this example located in developer tools in Chrome or FireFox? And/or how to unminify it?

[image]

Comment: is there an error in the code? if not why should it be debuggable?

Comment: Copy and paste into an IDE.

Comment: For what it's worth, the [code for the interactive examples on MDN web docs lies on GitHub](https://github.com/mdn/bob/).

Comment: @NinaScholz this site allows user to edit code before run, so it CAN have mistakes or some things user want to trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where it's located: probably in a dynamic module, possibly using `eval` or `new Function`, generated immediately before its run so you won't find it before that.

Instead, you can add a [`debugger` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) where you want a breakpoint, or just at the first line so it breaks into the right source module immediately and you can set other breakpoints in the debugger as needed.

Then open your devtools and run. Wait for it to break at the `debugger` statement and do your debugging.